# Data structure suitable for a windowing system

Tags: data-structures

I am working on a custom windowing system which has overlapping multiple windows shown at same time.

The important data about a window includes its coordinates(two diagonally opposite corners in x-y coordinate system), index(one with lowest index value is displayed above all other windows) and its contents.

The operations include

1. Clicking(Hit-testing)
2. Logging the history of windows worked with
   recently
3. Resizing
4. Dragging
5. Minimizing the window (which updates index to infinity/highest value)
6. Maximizing the window (which increments all other window index values by 1)

I have figured out that `Min-heap` can be used to keep track of windows with key being the index. The node of the tree can include other information like x-y coordinates and pointer to its contents.

History log can be done with `Doubly Linked Lists`.

**Questions**:

Which other data structure is suitable for this problem?

1. Is there any data structure that can single handedly solve this problem?
2. Is there any data structure that fits efficiently if minimize/maximize operations are excluded?
3. Does anyone knows how windows are kept track in OS like Windows Family, Linux, etc?

Comment: How do you select other windows? Is there a minimize operation or you just select the next window? And in that case where does the current top window go?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the obvious solution — to have an array of windows, an array of references for ordering, and an array of identifiers for history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like using a min-heap doesn't do you much good here. The only thing it's really good for is telling you which window is at the top of the z-order. It can't easily tell you what's in 2nd, 3rd, etc. place.

I think you should go with a linked list of windows, with the topmost window being the first node and the bottom-most window being the last.

Note that doing it this way doesn't require that you maintain an explicit number for each windows' z-order. The order is implicit in the list.

Hit testing is a simple matter of searching the list in order. Maximize a window by moving it to the front of the list. Minimize a window by moving it to the back of the list.

For logging history, use a separate linked list.

Resizing and dragging don't require special data structures.

If you want to display a task bar, you'll want to keep a list of windows that are in creation order. Otherwise every time you change the z-order of a window its position in the taskbar will change. That would be ... confusing.

I wouldn't recommend trying to build a single data structure that handles all of the use cases. If you do that, then if you want to change the way one thing works or if you want to add new functionality, you risk breaking everything else. But if you have the hit testing working with a linked list and you want to change the way the history works, you won't affect hit testing because it's a separate data structure.